# Populate array with unique values from a filtered column with multiple values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to populate an array with values from a column in a filtered Excel table.

In this column, the values may appear multiple times, but I need to return unique values, not all occurrences of each value.

```
Column F
a
a
a
b
c
c
a
b
d
```

The array would have a variable length and, based on the sample column would have the elements: {a, b, c, d}

The length of the array cannot be fixed because my function works with a filtered table that varies in length. Sometimes there may be only one unique value, other times there might be three.

I need to do this because my array will be used to determine the subject of an e-mail with, "... " & Array.

How do I extract unique values in a column to the array?

Comment: I would use a collection and loop through using `xlCellTypeVisible` more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells). For each item check if it doesn't exist, then add.

Comment: Could you please use the [edit] link to show what you've tried? (Such as creating the array with all the values.) That would give people a starting point to build on demonstrating the part that you're missing...

Comment: You may copy the filtered value to another range and use `RemoveDuplicates` to get unique values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Scripting.Dictionary` for such task and `xlCellTypeVisible`, example:

```
Sub sometest()
    Dim x As Long, cl As Range
    Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dic.comparemode = vbTextCompare

    x = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cl In Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(x, "A")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If Not dic.exists(cl.Value) Then
            dic.Add cl.Value, Nothing
        End If
    Next cl

    Debug.Print Join(dic.keys, ",")

End Sub
```

test:

[image]

Comment: Why not use `Dim dic As Scripting.Dictionary` instead of `Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`?

Comment: Also make OP aware that they will need to enable Microsoft Scripting Runtime in References in the VBE if using a dictionary.

Comment: @DeanDeVilliers there is no necessary of enabling Microsoft Scripting Runtime in References when used such approach of declaration `Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`. Your proposed approach of declaration `Dim dic As Scripting.Dictionary` require additional steps of enabling  Microsoft Scripting Runtime in References

Comment: Thank you Vasily, your solutions worked just fine.
Now I will try to understand how does it work, but I copied your code and it works.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use Scripting.Dictionary

You can select all the data from a column with `sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row` and then use a `Scripting.Dictionary` to find your unique values. Here's the code:

```
'Main Routine
Sub MyMacro()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim column As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim uniqueValues() As Variant

    Set sht = ActiveSheet 'Set your sheet here

    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    Set column = Range("F1:F" & LastRow)
    uniqueValues = getUniqueValues(column)
    'Do what you need to do with your values [...]
End Sub

'Return unique values from a Range
Function getUniqueValues(column As Range)
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary ' requires "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In column
        dict(cell.Value) = "1"
    Next

    'A double Transpose will put your data in an Array() format
    getUniqueValues = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(dict.Keys))
End Function
```

If you don't want to import `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`, use this code for `dict` declaration:

```
    'If you don't want to import Scripting Runtime, use this code
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

> **Note**: This is tested and works perfectly.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your solutions, it works as well as the one below.
I simply used the second proposal because I understand it better but I thank you anyway because I tried yours too and it works.